# Change Line Item value On a record on Field Change Event

Tags: netsuite

I have a field in sales order record. 
On change of that field I need to change a line item field.

[image: SalesOrder Record]

[image: LineItemTo Update]
I understand that client script is the only option.
The APIS we are looking at is nlapiSetLineItemValue and nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue

Seems  like it cant be possible in case of Line Item fields

```
function UpdateOrderTypeLocation(type, name, linenum) {

if(type=='item' && name =='item') {

    var orderType = nlapiGetFieldValue('custbody_ordertype');

    nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'custcolcustcol_line_order_type', linenum, orderType);
}
```

}

ANy workaround ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone but the API was looking for was nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue

```
nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'custcolcustcol_line_order_type', orderType);
```

I found I was writing the parameters wrong

Comment: Are you doing this thing on creation or updating of the record, How do you catch the field change event while creating of record?

Answer (score 0):

So is the line item already added in the SO when you trigger the script.  Should the script only trigger when the order type is changed?

Based on the code you provided, the script will trigger after you select an item and not when you select an order type.

Comment: Yes it should trigger on selecting item. The script is triggered right.

And no line item is not added. It should basically trigger before line item is added. More precisely when Item is selected in line item